# How to prove that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is countable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My assumption is to use Cantor-Bernstein Theorem and formulating function $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ that is injective and function $g: \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ that is also injective and conclude that it is countable. But the problem is that the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ includes negative numbers and the mere creation of functions like $f(a,b) = 2^a\cdot3^b$ that is used in proving the countability of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ wouldn't cut it.

So what could be the possible function to use?

Comment: a map from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb N$ could help

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ injects into $\Bbb N$ via say $a\mapsto (3a+1)^2$.

Comment: good point, so can I use that and instead inject say (a,b) ↦ (a+b)^2?

Comment: That's not an injection, $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ map to the same value .

Comment: I think it's simpler to just come up with a sequence of elements of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ which covers all elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about arranging $Z\times Z$ by spiraling out around $(0,0)$?

$$ (0,0), (1,0),(1,1), (0,1), (-1,1), (-1,0),(-1,-1), (0,-1), (-1,-1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),...$$

Comment: I've thought of that, in fact I've already done that but I'm worried that it might not be enough to prove it? Or is it? That's why I'm trying to think of a function to satisfy the problem.

Comment: Once you have a sequence which covers all the elements you are done. If you try you may be able to find  a formula for this as well.

Comment: Did you spiral around the Cartesian plane?

Comment: @Minuet Starting with the $(0,0)$ I traced the square centered at the origin with size three, counter clock wise and after that the square of size $5$ and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is that the set of integers Z includes negative numbers and the mere creation of functions like f(a,b) = (2^a)(3^b) that is used in proving the countability of N x N wouldn't cut it.

Well, $\mathbb Z$ is injective to $\mathbb N$ supposedly.  Which means, in theory, there is a bijection $j:\mathbb Z  \to N$.  So if you think $f:\mathbb N\times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is injective.  Then $h(a,b) = f(j(a),j(b))$ so $h: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ will be injective.

So do you know what a bijection from $j:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$ could be?

Example let $j(x) = 2x+1$ if $x\ge 0$ and $j(x) = 2|x|$ if $x< 0$ is good bijection $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$.  The positive numbers (and zero) get mapped to the positive odds and the negative numbers get mapped to the positive evens.

The $f(j(a),j(b)) = 2^{2a+1; a\ge 0:2|a|; a< 0}*3^{2b+1; b\ge 0:2|b|; b < 0}$ is injective.

=====

Or you could do $f(a,b) = 2^a3^b$ if $a>0; b>5$ and $f(a,b) = 5^{|a|+1}3^b$ if $a \le 0; b> 0$ and $f(a,b)= 2^a7^{|b|+1}$ if $a>0; b\le 0$ and $f(a,b)= 5^{|a|+1}7^{|b|+1}$ if $a\le 0; b\le 0$.

Be creative!